# How should I make user parameter match with one of the elements of bash array

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

BASH Script (regex and array related)

```
declare -A colours=( [red]="0;31" [RED]="1;31" )

echo -ne '\e['${colours[$1]}m
```

Question: echoc Red WORLD

--> this should print WORLD in bold red colour.
How should I make Red match with RED?

Comment: Are you asking how to make `Red` match `RED` and not `red`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion:

```
    colour=${1^^*}
    shift

    echo -ne '\e['${colours[$colour]}m "$@"
```

`^^` changes matching characters to upper case, `*` matches all characters.

Comment: This would convert `red` to `RED` as well, not just `Red` (if I understand the question correctly).